# Usar la función fzero de Matlab

Tags: matlab

Tengo el siguiente problema. Necesito usar fzero en Matlab para calcular los ceros de una función, pero dicha función la tengo como una variable y no entiendo bien como se hace pues en todos los ejemplo usan referencias:

En los ejemplo he visto algo así:

```
syms x
y = @(x) x+5;
fzero(y, -4)
```

Así si funciona, pues desde que se definió la función se hizo lo de la referencia. Pero en mi caso es una función que se obtiene de unos datos y no se como hacer funcionar el método fzero, o sea, no se como pasar por referencia esa ecuación que tengo en memoria. Disculpen mi ignorancia, agradecería enormemente cualquier ayuda. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoro la naturaleza de la función que tienes en memoria y que has calculado previamente. Ahora bien, si puedes transformarla en caracteres, la función fzero admite también la siguiente sintaxis:

```
syms x

f = 'x + 5';

fzero(f, -4)
```

Con la función `char()` puedes transformar una expresión simbólica en caracteres:

```
f = x + 5; % Expresión simbólica obtenida mediante el cálculo.

p = char(f); % Ahora la expresión es de caracteres

[vx, vy] = fzero(p, -4)
```

Ahora un ejemplo completo con una función cualquiera de la que queremos obtener sus ceros en la primera derivada:

```
y = 2*sin(x) + cos(2*x);    % Una función simbólica cualquiera
dy = diff(y)                % derivada simbólica de la función anterior
dychar = char(dy)           % Transformación a carácter de la derivada simbólica
[vx, vy] = fzero(dychar, 4) % llamada a fzero con función carácter
```

Espero que ta haya servido.

Un saludo